# Difference between copy.copy and dataclasses.replace

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

To my understanding, `dataclasses.replace(x)` does the same thing as `copy.copy(x)`, except it only works if `x` is a `dataclass`, and offers the ability to replace members. However I've also noticed it's about 3x faster. I'm curious now why `copy` would be so much slower, and if there are other differences between the two functions that should be considered.

```
import dataclasses
import time
import copy

@dataclasses.dataclass()
class X:
    x=1
    y=1
    z=1

x = X()

start = time.perf_counter()
for _ in range(100000):
    a = dataclasses.replace(x)
t1 = time.perf_counter() - start

start = time.perf_counter()
for _ in range(100000):
    a = copy.copy(x)
t2 = time.perf_counter() - start

print(t1)  # 0.4
print(t2)  # 1.2
```

Comment: Guessing that `copy()` has to do some extra type checking?

Comment: Using `timeit` confirms the time difference, .e.g `timeit.timeit('copy.copy(x)', setup='from __main__ import dataclasses, x, copy')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Chris_Rands](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6260170/chris-rands) alluded to in their comment, `copy.copy` has quite a bit of extra logic needed to handle arbitrary Python objects—this extra logic likely accounts for the difference in speed. In contrast, `dataclasses.replace` can get away with only making a few checks since the function only needs to work for dataclasses. You can see how much simpler `dataclasses.replace` is than `copy.copy` (and the functions it calls) in the source code for [dataclasses.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/dataclasses.py#L1399) and [copy.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/copy.py#L66).

If you look at the source for `copy.copy`, you will notice that the code that copies an `X` object boils down to this.

```py
def fastcopy(x):
    red = getattr(x,"__reduce_ex__")(4)
    return red[0](*red[1])
```

Without the extra checks, this `fastcopy` function seems to perform comparably to `dataclasses.replace`. The full code I tested with is below, along with the times I got.

```py
import dataclasses
import time
import copy

def fastcopy(x):
    red = getattr(x,"__reduce_ex__")(4)
    return red[0](*red[1])

@dataclasses.dataclass()
class X:
    x=1
    y=1
    z=1

x = X()

start = time.perf_counter()
for _ in range(100000):
    a = dataclasses.replace(x)
t1 = time.perf_counter() - start

start = time.perf_counter()
for _ in range(100000):
    a = fastcopy(x)
t2 = time.perf_counter() - start

print(t1) # 0.1
print(t2) # 0.1
```